# Google Analytics User-ID-status showing as "Unassigned"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have this scenario

I enabled User-ID feature and Session Unification feature.

On the frontend when someone Signup I set their newly created UserId and I trigger custom event, that says that someone signed up.

Then I trigger another custom event from the backend that say that user becomes a friend with someone (need to do this fro the backend) and I'm using Measurement Protocol for this hitting this endpoint when this happens `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=trackingId&uid=uid&ec=eventCategory&ea=eventAction&el=eventLabel`

Now the problem that I have is that I did a small test, where I registered 2 users, and for one I become a friend with someone just to see if that event triggers too

Inisde the Realtime everything works as expected, but when the reports show up the next day I got **1 user with status Unassigned**

Any Ideas what can break this flow and how this can happen? I thought If data in realtime is ok that it will be on reports too, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miss `&` before `ea` parameter. This can make issue because event action will not recognized and it is a required parameter.

**EDIT**

if you have done the tests too far apart (30 minutes) you can generate some inconsistencies due to the session, considering that you send an event.

Note: real-time data is generally unreliable.

Comment: Sry this was a mistake when I was coping the code from the codebase I have & before ea parameter.


Is it possible to do what I'm trying? Basically I need a way to identify the user on the backend and trigger event for him and I'm doing that whit User ID

Also one thing I forgot to mention is that on the frontend I have GTM

Comment: Can it be an issue that I was registering multiple users from the same browser? Now after thinking about it that could explain having only one user showing and status unassigned since there was probably multiple different UserID pushes

So I probably need to find a better way to test this?

Comment: I updated the answer, however I would do a new test avoiding complications.

Comment: Thanks man! I approved the answer, just to be sure my understanding of the session unification is correct, if I push custom event with USER ID set from the Measurement Protocol, it will get associated with the Event that was pushed from the client side where userId is set inside the session, correct?

Comment: An event may be associated to a session not ti another event. Two events may be associated to the same session.